# downloaded and deployed the tutorial but cant start instance: Form failure: Not Found

Tags: camunda

I downloaded and deployed the loan-approval tutorial but everytime I want to start an instance:  Form failure: Not Found

any idea what could be wrong?

server 7.5.0 with tomcat on OS X -- nothing configured, all standard.. as by the tutorial

Comment: When does the exception appear? Do you have the `request-loan.html` in the `src/main/webapp/forms` folder?

Comment: Some trace, please?

Comment: @JanGalinski the logs are empty

Comment: @Zelldon add it as answer and feel free to call me stupid

Comment: Normal question, no reason for hate. How do you start the instance?

Comment: @Zelldon no soorry - I meant it. that is my mistake! :D sorry

Comment: @Daij-Djan aaah ok :) i put it as answer. Best regards, Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that the `request-loan.html` file, which should look like this:

```
<form name="requestLoan">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="customerId">Customer ID</label>
    <input class="form-control"
           cam-variable-type="String"
           cam-variable-name="customerId"
           name="customerId" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="amount">Amount</label>
    <input class="form-control"
           cam-variable-type="Double"
           cam-variable-name="amount"
           name="amount" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Is located in the `src/main/webapp/forms` folder.
Like is written [here](https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/bpmn20/forms/#add-a-start-form)